Probability of A occurring $m$ times in a row before B occurs $n$ times
I think my question is slightly different than this question
this.
My question is: given event $A$ with probability $p$, and $B$ with probability of $1-p$, what are the odds of $A$ occurring $m$ times in a row, before $B$ occurs $n$ times.
So in a game of coin flipping, what is the probability of

flipping Heads twice in a row before flipping ten tails
flipping Heads three times in a row before flipping ten tails

So
H T T T H T H T H T T H T T T would be a fail
H T T T H H would be a success
I don't even know where to begin the only formula I know that would vaguely apply is
P(A) before n B's $= 1-P(B)^n$

Please edit to include your efforts.  Note that recursive methods seem natural.

For what it's worth, virtually every MathSE posted question that I have seen, that followed this article on MathSE protocol has been upvoted rather than downvoted.  I am not necessarily advocating this protocol.  Instead, I am merely stating a fact: if you scrupulously follow the linked article, skipping/omitting nothing, you virtually guarantee a positive response.

Tough crowd. So I need to know probability before asking questions to know more about probability

There is no consistency in having 3 upvotes on the linked question while this one, which shows more thought, gets 3 downvotes.

Problem: We have a sequence of mutually independent coin flip events $\{H_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ with $P[H_i]=p$ (assume $0<p<1$). We say coin flip $i$ produces heads if event $H_i$ is true, and tails if $H_i^c$ is true.
Fix $m,k\in\{1, 2, 3, …\}$. We want to know the probability that we have at least one run length of  $m$ or more heads in a row before accumulating a total of $k$ tails.
Approach: We can define subexperiment $n \in \{1,2,3,...\}$ as a fresh batch of independent coin flips until we either get a tails or we get $m$ heads in a row. So each subexperiment has a variable number of flips (it can be as short as 1 flip or as long as $m$ flips). Define $A_n$ as the event that subexperiment $n$ ends with getting $m$ heads before a single tail.
Exercises:

Explain the possible sequences of coin flips in one particular subexperiment.

Compute $P[A_n]$ and $P[A_n^c]$ for each $n \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$. Explain why $\{A_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ are mutually independent events with $P[A_n]$ being the same for all $n$.

Explain the desired problem in terms of the $A_1, A_2, A_3,....$ events.

Solve the desired problem in terms of $m,k,p$.


